# problems installing clojure lein under mac os 10.13.6

Tags: clojure

I am using Homebrew with the  command brew install leiningen but trying `lein repl` gives

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.uti

l.Map$Entr
```

followed by many pages ending with

```
clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
```

the same happens with Macports or supplied script, `boot`  installs  perfectly with Homebrew.
I am  learning Clojure from the  Brave and True book which needs lein repl

Comment: would you consider not using homebrew as a possible solution? "installing" leingen is quite straight forward. Whats your java varsion `java --version`?

Comment: I use Java 8, emacs26.1

Answer (score 0):

To "install" lein just download the download script from the web page and run it :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `sdkman`, even if leiningen is straightforward to use:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Then **open a new terminal** and type:

```
sdk install leiningen
```

Now try your:

```
lein repl
```

While you're at it, `sdk` can be used to manage your Java installations. Never again worry about dirtying your system with various versions, as they all go in your home directory, cleanly.

Comment: same as  before,  do protections need changing?

Comment: where does sdk put things